# WP Получение списка заголовка всех постов и их ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как в WordPress вывести в элемент все доступные опубликованные посты, а для option в качестве параметра value держать id этих постов для последующей работы с ними.

```html
<select size="3" name="wp-posts">
  <option value="1">Post1</option>
  <option value="23">Post2</option>
  <option value="23">Post3</option>
  <option value="4">Post4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё довольно просто:

```
<?php
$query_args = [
    'post_status' => 'publish',
];

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

?>
    <select size="3" name="wp-posts">
        <?php
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
<?php
```